# How To Sum NoofHours in SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012-express

i have a table which contain a column **NoofHours** and data type is in datetime now i want to sum the values like 9:30 + 9:45 = 19:15(HH:MM) Format kindly Help.

Comment: It's not easy because SQL Server doesn't have a data type that represents a *timespan*. Does this have to be done in the database? C# *does* have access to a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) data type that naturally supports addition.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sum(NoofHours) as sumO
FROM YourTable
Group By NoofHours
```

Comment: You rarely, if ever, want to `GROUP` on the same columns that you're computing aggregates for.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you:

```
SELECT convert(time,DATEADD(hh,SUM(DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(DATETIME,tm,108))), DATEADD(n,SUM(DATEPART(n,CONVERT(DATETIME,tm,108))),'1900.01.01') )) FROM temp
```

I've also created a SQLFiddle for you to test with [SQLFIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/171b0/11)